# Is it possible that a person will finds the number what his friend thinks in my mind. the number should between 1-100 via java code

Tags: puzzle

1. the person will think a number between 1-100. The Questionnaire can ask n number of
   condition, i.e the number is even or odd, the number is perfect
   square or prime number, sum of squares etc.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible to find a number between 1 and 100 by asking 100 questions, namely:

1. Is the number one?
2. Is the number two?

   etc., etc., etc.

It is possible to do it with 7 questions by binary search. Writing the number in base 2, ask:

1. Is the units bit one?
2. Is the twos bit one?
3. Is the fours bit one?

   etc., etc., etc.

I don't know anything about Java code, but that's for a different website, anyway.

Comment: Indeed, even 7 questions of the form "Is the number greater than $x$?" will do. (Hint: start with $x=50$.) The binary expansion technique does, however, have the advantage that you can decide all the questions you will ask in advance.